# Setting a primary attribute via form radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

So I'm having an issue setting a primary image for my Dress object via a form.
The form allows the user to edit the dress details and then add/remove images to the form (using nested_form) and for each of them set a label and assign a primary image.

Everything works so far except for setting the primary image via radio buttons.

Dress Model:

```
class Dress < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :dress_images
    has_one :primary_dress_image, :class_name => "DressImage", :conditions => { :is_primary => true }

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :dress_images, :allow_destroy => true

    validates :name, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 99 }

end
```

DressImage Model

```
class DressImage < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :dress

    # Same as:
    # def self.primary
    #   where(:is_primary => true)
    # end
    scope :primary, where(:is_primary => true)

    # clear old primary if:
    # this is a new record
    # this is existing and is_primary has been set to true
    before_save :clear_primary,
                            :if => Proc.new{ |r| (r.new_record? && r.is_primary) || (r.is_primary_changed? && r.is_primary) }

    validates :label, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 60 }
    validates :caption, :length => { :maximum => 200 }

    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

    def clear_primary
        DressImage.update_all( {:is_primary => false}, :dress_id => self.dress_id )
    end

end
```

Dress edit form

```
<h1>Dress</h1>

    <% @dress.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>   <%#= f.label :name %>

    <%= nested_form_for @dress, :as => :dress, :url => { :action => :update }, :html=>{ :multipart => true } do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>

        <%= f.label :description %>
        <%= f.text_area :description %>

        <%= f.fields_for :dress_images do |dress_image_form| %>

            <div class="dress-image">

                <%= image_tag dress_image_form.object.image_url(:thumb) %>

                <%= dress_image_form.text_field :label %>
            <%= dress_image_form.file_field :image %>

            <div class="primary-image-radio">
                <%= dress_image_form.label :is_primary, "Main Image" %>
                <%= f.radio_button :primary_dress_image_id, dress_image_form.object.id %>

            </div>

            <p>
                <%= dress_image_form.link_to_remove "Remove this attachment" %>
            </p>

        </div>

    <% end %>

  <%= f.link_to_add "Add Photo", :dress_images %>

    <%= f.submit "Save Dress" %>

<% end %>
```

With this radio button, the primary_dress_image_id attribute is set on the Dress object, but @dress.primary_dress_image gives a different result to the ID.

If I change the radio button to `<%= dress_image_form.radio_button :is_primary, true %>` it works better but because the name of each radio button is different, they are not treated as the same group.

I'm new to rails so I might be missing something completely obvious or doing it all wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using this method: `<%= dress_image_form.radio_button :is_primary, true %>` and using jquery to deselect all the other radio buttons when one is clicked.
This seems like a bit of a hacky method to me - there must be a purely Rails way of doing this without having to resort to JS? Until I find a better one, I'm going to stick with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution.
Add a hidden input to each of your nested field groups. Use a `radio_button_tag` instead of `radio_button` to make sure they are in the same group:

```
<div class="dress-image">
  <%= dress_image_form.hidden_field :is_primary, :class => 'primary-image' %>
  ...
  <%= radio_button_tag "select_primary_image", true, dress_image_form.object.is_primary? %>
  ...
</div>
```

Then add some javascript to update the hidden field according to the radio button selection:

```
$("body").on "change", ".primary-image-radio input:radio" ->
  $(@).closest(".dress-image").find(".primary-image").val( $(@).is(":checked") )
```

You might need to modify the code a little because it's just an untested quick example, but it should give you an idea.